# how to solve the Java upgrade 15 to 16 issue with Castor - XML

Tags: java, spring

I have upgraded the java version from 15 to 16 and getting the below error on runtime.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate serializer com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.exolab.castor.xml.BaseXercesJDK5Serializer cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not  export com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize to unnamed module @646cb2e

Comment: Well ... you shouldn't be upgrading to Java 16 because Java 16 is already end-of-life.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the property to use own Xerces to prevent the problem.

```java
context.setProperty(org.castor.xml.XMLProperties.SERIALIZER_FACTORY,
    org.exolab.castor.xml.XercesXMLSerializerFactory.class.getName());
```

Change

```java
Marshaller marshaller = new Marshaller(myWriter);
```

to something like this:

```java
StringWriter myWriter= new StringWriter(); 
XMLContext xmlContext = new XMLContext();
xmlContext.setProperty(org.castor.xml.XMLProperties.SERIALIZER_FACTORY, 
    org.exolab.castor.xml.XercesXMLSerializerFactory.class.getName());
Marshaller marshaller = xmlContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setWriter(myWriter);
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue when I was migrating to openjdk17 from 8. @Miriam answer was the key, but it was not enough as I am also using Casor XML Schema. The solution was to add latest xerces jar and castor.properties to the classpath containing this single line (in my case):

`org.exolab.castor.xml.serializer.factory=org.exolab.castor.xml.XercesXMLSerializerFactory`

This documentation might be useful for further help:
https://castor-data-binding.github.io/castor/reference-guide/reference/xml/xml-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have encountered another manifestation of https://github.com/castor-data-binding/castor/issues/76 (closed).

This kind of thing is caused by application code (e.g. Castor) directly referring to internal JDK classes (in this case `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer`).   This should be raised as an Castor issue.

Unfortunately, it looks like Castor data bindings is a moribund project, so you may need to develop your own fix to get it to work on Java 16 and later.

If you are going to do that, this is where the JDK internal package name is injected:

https://github.com/castor-data-binding/castor/blob/master/xml/src/main/java/org/exolab/castor/xml/

Look at `XercesJDK5Serializer.java` `BaseXercesJDK5Serializer.java`

Comment: If possible can you please explain in detail about the fix can be implemented for this castor issue.

Comment: Well ... given that I haven't done it myself, no I can't.   But you need the code that is trying to create an instance of `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer` with something that uses an `XMLSerializer` that is ... not part of the the JDK internals.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the [--add-exports](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/migrate/migrating-jdk-8-later-jdk-releases.html#GUID-2F61F3A9-0979-46A4-8B49-325BA0EE8B66) JVM option:

```
--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize=ALL-UNNAMED
```

We did a JDK 8 -> 17 migration, and the error message can indicate the solution. In your case:

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate serializer com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.exolab.castor.xml.BaseXercesJDK5Serializer cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer (in module java.xml) **because module java.xml does not export com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize to unnamed module** @646cb2e*

If the error contained: **module java.base does not opens java.lang to unnamed module**

You would use `--add-opens` instead of `--add-exports`:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```